# Not able to click on links in webpage on ie 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, hyperlink, internet-explorer-8

I am not able to click on anything on my url page http://www.travelacademyofindia.com in ie 8. It works fine on Mozilla and Chrome. Also, other website page of mine http://www.bhojresort.com has no issues on ie 8.

Can some body tell me could this be a html coding error or a css error or what else is interfering with the clickability only on this site >

Comment: Any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: No error at all @epascarello

Answer (score 0):

The filters defined in your Stylesheet on `html` and `body` do prevent 'event bubbling' as they are placed/rendered above your pages elements.

Try to disable them for IE8...

Comment: Hi @wolfflow ...thanks for the answer...it works... But the problem is then how do I get my background image to fill screen in IE without the filter ?!

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED ! It was an ie bug !

Solution was simple. just had to mark up the links in css as a{position:relative}

I got the solution from here http://www.daltonlp.com/view/217. Answer by Greg.

Was a life saver !